# Trying ti install tensorflow on PC

Tags: tensorflow, pip

In attempting to install tensorflow on my PC with `pip install tensorflow` (no quotes) I get the following message:

```
Error: could not find version that satifies the requirement tensorflow (from versions: none). No matching distribution distribution found in tensorflow.
```

Answer (score 0):

Question, do you have an updated version of Python? Verify that you are running a Python 2.7.0 or higher version with:

```
python --version
```

If you do, try this command:

```
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestions:

1. First of all, [here's a complete pip install guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) - This one is quite elaborate and all the steps are explained in detail. Just following that should work fine.
2. [Here is the official Tensorflow install page](https://www.tensorflow.org/install) that has other options as well such as Docker
3. Just in case your pip defaults to the Python2.7 version, try using pip3 instead of pip. I think MacOS still uses Python 2.7 as its default version. Not sure though
4. You might be using a very old version of pip. try upgrading pip with `pip install --upgrade pip`
5. I would recommend using conda installer if pip is not working for you. [Here is a great article which details the steps for installation and usage with conda](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/install-tensorflow-2-0-along-with-all-packages-on-anaconda-for-windows-10-and-ubuntu-86a89ba51983)
6. If it still doesn't work, try sharing more details such as pip version, Python version, etc

Answer (score 0):

Few things to keep in mind (for python3 similarly select for your python version), :

- Upgrade pip:
  `sudo -H python3  -m pip install --upgrade pip`
- Install appropriate tensorflow version (shown here 1.15)

  For cpu: `sudo -H python3 -m pip install tensorflow==1.15`

  For gpu: `sudo -H python3 -m pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.15`